# add class to two different button in x-editable angular

Tags: html, css, angular, x-editable

here I want to add two different class to two button using **x-editable angular**.

[image]

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div>Email: <a href="#" editable-email="user.email">{{ user.email || 'empty' }}</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure for all the buttons at once like so

```
app.run(function(editableOptions, editableThemes) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
  editableThemes.bs3.buttonsClass = 'class1';
});
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions, editableThemes) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
  editableThemes.bs3.buttonsClass = 'class1';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
  };
});
```

```css
div[ng-app] {
  margin: 50px;
}

.class1 {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<h4>Angular-xeditable Customize input (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" e-required e-placeholder="Enter name" e-class="class1 class2">
    {{ (user.name || 'empty') | uppercase }}
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: no, I want to add a direct class in the button element. @Naren Murali

Comment: @AnjaliPatel is this issue resolved?